# Map GeoJSON to Java with Jackson

Tags: java, json, mapping, geojson

I am trying to map a JSON file into Java objects using Jackson library. This json file is a multi-level file that can be found here:

https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson

It is the list of earthquakes that happened in the last 30 days in the US.

Here is the structure of this son file: https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php

Now, I wrote a Java program that is reading fields from this file, specifically I am trying to access the field which is under features -> properties -> place (e.g. from the original file "place":"17km NW of Pinnacles, CA")). When I get to the properties field I can read it as a LinkedHashMap, **but the next level, so the keys and values of this LinkedHashMap are being read as Strings:**

**for example this is one of the values : {type=Point, coordinates=[-121.2743333, 36.6375, 8.61]}**

**I WANT TO READ THESE VALUES AS ANOTHER OBJECT (NOT STRING, MAP MAYBE?) SO I COULD EXTRACT FURTHER DATA FROM IT.**

Here is my class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ReadJSONFile {

    private StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

public void convert_json_to_java() throws Exception {

    String url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in .readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(inputLine);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
        } in.close();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void map_to_object() throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    //ignore fields that are not formatted properly
    om.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    Map<Object, Object> resultMap = om.readValue(stringBuffer.toString(), Map.class);
    ArrayList<Object> featuresArrayList = (ArrayList<Object>) resultMap.get("features");

    for(Object o : featuresArrayList) {
        LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> propertiesMap = (LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>) o;
        for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : propertiesMap.entrySet()) {

            //HERE IS THE PROBLEM, THE VALUES OF THIS MAP (SECOND OBJECT) IS BEING READ AS A STRING
            //WHILE SOME VALUES ARE NOT A STRING:
            //e.g. {type=Point, coordinates=[-121.2743333, 36.6375, 8.61]}
            //AND I WANT TO READ IT AS A MAP OR ANY OTHER OBJECT THAT WOULD ALLOW ME TO ACCESS THE DATA
            String propertiesMapValues = entry.getValue().toString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        ReadJSONFile rjf = new ReadJSONFile();
        rjf.convert_json_to_java();
        rjf.map_to_object();
    }
}
```

Maven dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl

When I try casting this last object to anything else than String, the program gives me exception (can't cast String to another object). Did I do something wrong? Can someone tell me what can I do to access those fields without modifying Strings (e.g. splitting them into arrays etc.)?

Comment: Is there some specific reason for not creating DTOs and readinf values straight into those?

Comment: Thanks for writing a complete and runnable example! Your code works for me -- In the inner loop I get a key of "properties" with a concrete value type of LinkedHashMap, containing keys like "place". Can you show the code you were trying to use before you introduced `toString()`?

Comment: I did use a different Jackson version:         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Works with your dependency too.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't put the toString() there by mistake? `entry.getValue()` is an Object, so you can cast it to anything. (Although of course you'll get a runtime error if it isn't what you think it is)

Comment: Or perhaps the problem is that you are trying to cast every `entry.getValue()` to a Map? Some are Strings, so you will get a runtime error.You will need to check that the entry.getKey() is "properties" (which you know has a Map as a value) before casting the value.

Comment: Yes, of course, the problem was that I was trying to cast everything as a Map, and some fields were just Strings (it works the other way around, fields that could be a map are easily being cast to a String). Thank you! Now if I get the specific key value I get a Map as a result! Thank you again! It works like a charm!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your code works but it could be a bit simplified. The method `convert_json_to_java` is unnecessary, you can pass the URL directly to the ObjectMapper.

The values in the map are not read as Strings, but you are converting them to Strings by calling `toString()`, which is defined for all objects. Acctual types can be Map, List, String, Integer etc., depending on the JSON content. Working with a generic map is indeed a bit annoying, so I would suggest you converting values to structured objects. GeoJSON is an open standard, so there are open-source libraries facilitating using it, e.g. [geojson-jackson](https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson).

You would need to add a maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.grundid.opendatalab</groupId>
    <artifactId>geojson-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then the program could look something like:

```
import org.geojson.*

// ...

public class ReadJSONFile {

    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    public void mapToObject(String url) throws Exception {

        Map<String, Object> resultMap = om.readValue(new URL(url), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
        List<Feature> features = om.convertValue(resultMap.get("features"), new TypeReference<List<Feature>>() {});

        for(Feature f : features) {
            // Write the feature to the console to see how it looks like
            System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(f));
            // Extract properties
            Map<String,Object> properties = f.getProperties();
            // ....
            // Extract geometry
            GeoJsonObject geometry = f.getGeometry();
            if(geometry instanceof Point) {
                Point p = (Point) geometry;
                // do something with the point
            }  else if(geometry instanceof LineString) {
                LineString mls = (LineString) geometry;
                // ...
            } else if(geometry instanceof MultiLineString) {
                MultiLineString mls = (MultiLineString) geometry;
                // ...
            } else if(geometry instanceof MultiPoint) {
                MultiPoint mp = (MultiPoint) geometry;
                // ...
            } else if(geometry instanceof Polygon) {
                Polygon pl = (Polygon) geometry;
                // ...
            } else if(geometry != null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled geometry type: " + geometry.getClass().getName());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ReadJSONFile rjf = new ReadJSONFile();
        rjf.mapToObject("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I actually found a way to shorten my code using Jackson library, by reading directly JSON file into the Object Mapper and omitting convert_json_to_java() method: Map<Object, Object> resultMap = om.readValue(new URL("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson"),new TypeReference<Map<Object, Object>>() {});

Comment: I used toString() method to objects which are Strings already, if I tried to map them to anything else the program was returning a runtime error. That's why I used this method. I am still new to JSON, so I will definitely analyse your code and try also creating objects using geojson :) Thanks!